# Google Place - set On Info Window Click Listener

Tags: android, api, loops, maps, clicklistener

How I can setOnInfoWindowClickListener if have this loop?
I'm trying to create an Android application. To retrieve data from json file I use retrofit. 
I need help when clicking on the info window I want to show more information about the clicked place. 
I want to display Toast with the name of clicked the Nearby Places.

```
for (int i = 0; i < response.body().getResults().size(); i++) {
                Double lat = response.body().getResults().get(i).getGeometry().getLocation().getLat();
                Double lng = response.body().getResults().get(i).getGeometry().getLocation().getLng();
                final String placeName = response.body().getResults().get(i).getName();
                // String vicinity = response.body().getResults().get(i).getVicinity();
                // Double ratting = response.body().getResults().get(i).getRating();
                final List <String> nameLocation = new ArrayList<>();
                nameLocation.add(placeName);

                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                // Position of Marker on Map
                markerOptions.position(latLng);
                // Adding Title to the Marker
                markerOptions.title(placeName);
                // Adding colour to the marker
                markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(markerColor));

                // Adding Marker to the Camera.
                Marker mMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                // move map camera
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12));



            }
```

Comment: What kind of extra info do you want to display, and in what manner? Do you want to show a separate activity or maybe an overlay? The question is a little unclear on the goal you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to display Toast with the name of the clicked place.

Comment: You should update the text of the question with answers to clarifying questions. Comments can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in the comments, you can show a toast in when a marker on your map is clicked by doing the following.

First attach a marker click listener to your map:

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener {
  public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
    //TODO: Show your toast    
  }
});
```

Next within the click handler, create a new toast. Make sure you have the application context within this handler, so that you can attach the toast to that context.

```
final Context context = this;

mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener {
  public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, marker.getTitle(), "Additional info",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
  }
});
```

Comment: Just have same result. I have loop.